# javascript concate nested array object value

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, concatenation

Hi I have the below JSON file with nested object:

```
{
  "Maps": {
    "Campus": [
      {
        "name": "nus",
        "Building": [
          {
            "name": "sde1",
            "Floor": [
              {
                "name": "floor1"
              },
              {
                "name": "floor2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "sde2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ntu",
        "Building": [
          {
            "name": "ece1",
            "Floor": [
              {
                "name": "floor1"
              },
              {
                "name": "floor2"
              },
              {
                "name": "floor3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ece2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to use javascript or node.js modules to parse the above JSON file and get the below format in an array:

```
nus>sde1>floor1
nus>sde1>floor2
ntu>ece1>floor1
ntu>ece1>floor2
ntu>ece1>floor3
```

basically I have to concatenate the `Campus Name` with `Building Name` and `Floor name` and put a `<` symbol in between.

If the nested object field `Floor` is not exist, ignore the parse and continue the next child object.

How to achieve that in an easy way? thanks.

Comment: Write function that take this json and return array. I guess it will be simple loop.

Comment: @Oxi, I tried to use loop but I thought there may be some modules such as `underscore` to make the code concise and short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `forEach()` loop and add to array.

```js
var obj = {"Maps":{"Campus":[{"name":"nus","Building":[{"name":"sde1","Floor":[{"name":"floor1"},{"name":"floor2"}]},{"name":"sde2"}]},{"name":"ntu","Building":[{"name":"ece1","Floor":[{"name":"floor1"},{"name":"floor2"},{"name":"floor3"}]},{"name":"ece2"}]}]}}

var result = [];
obj.Maps.Campus.forEach(function(e) {
  e.Building.forEach(function(a) {
    if (a.Floor) {
      a.Floor.forEach(function(c) {
        result.push(e.name + '>' + a.name + '>' + c.name);
      })
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```